# Gtk hiding window on it's callback

Tags: c++, gtk

I have a function that I want to hide on pressing a button. I've read that I can define multiple callbacks on a signal and they will be called in the same order as defined. So I wanted to execute two functions on button press and I wanted one of them to hide window that contains this button. I tried to do it like this:

```
g_signal_connect(btn_confirm, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(function_that_does_stuff), NULL);
g_signal_connect(btn_confirm, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), add_conn_win);
...
void kill_window ( GtkWidget* wdgt, GtkWidget* win )
{
  gtk_widget_hide_all(win);
}
```

But this isn't working. Window's still there. Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: How are you showing the window? Have you checked your callbacks are being triggered? From the code snippet it sounds like the window is being used as a dialog box. If so, have you tried using GtkDialog? Finally, you probably don't want to use _hide_all because that will mark all the widgets in the window as hidden as well, which probably isn't what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, see what the documentation says about [gtk_widget_hide_all()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide-all):

> gtk_widget_hide_all has been deprecated since version 2.24 and should not be used in newly-written code

Instead you should use [gtk_widget_hide ()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide). The specification says that it

> Reverses the effects of gtk_widget_show(), causing the widget to be hidden (invisible to the user).

As a comment said, make sure your callbacks are being triggered. Then try

`gtk_widget_hide (win);`

I think that should do the work, let me know if it helps!

Comment: It worked, actually I think it was OK all the time but the callback wasn't triggered for some unknown reason. Thank you for your help.